# Add second counter to a gif file

Tags: windows, gif

I am looking for a Microsoft Windows program that can automatically add second counter to a gif file (or some other kind of time counter).

E.g., given the gif file

[image]

I would like to add somewhere (ideally configurable) some time indication such as "0 second", "1 second", etc.

By "automatically add", I mean I don't want to have to edit each frame one by one myself. The less work I have to do, the better.

Any price or license is fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the first time I have seen a question about adding second counter to GIF, so I decided to add this feature to ezgif.com

You can upload the GIF at http://ezgif.com/effects and select "add second counter", it will give some additional options.

If you have any questions or suggestions, feel free to ask :)

[image: second counter interface]

[image: second counter example]

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly can do this from the command line with [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) by using [GIF Animations Annotations](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#annotating) in a [frame-by-frame](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#frame_mod) manner but you will have to spend some time playing about with the parameters and might need to use one of the language bindings.

Comment: Thanks, yes probably would need a bit of coding / CLI magic around. Btw I am surprised you don't point to the Python Imaging Library  :)